# Search Attached Sources in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, constants

Is there any way that Eclipse will let me search within attached sources of referenced libraries?

I'm trying to find all the places where a `public static final String` constant is used.

Comment: This is old, but did you ever figure it out? :)

Answer (score -1):

Select needed text and press `CTRL + ALT + G`. It performs search on whole workspace.

Comment: He want to search also in the attached sources of the libraries he use, not only in the workspace ...